# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync: With many file downloads

Tags: c#, webclient, download

I am using multiple instances of the `WebClient` class in order to download many small files at the same time asynchronously from a web server on the internet.
The URI i'm using has it's IP in number notation to avoid unnecessary DNS resolutions.

I am pushing it a bit, using e.g. 50+ instances of the class at the same time.

What I noticed is that although most files are downloaded correctly, a small percentage of them have 0 length, meaning that thread never completed succesfully -- maybe due to an error.
However the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` never reported an error.

Am I pushing it too much? But then again, shouldn't it give off an error?

Comment: Have you got a code snippet that reproduces/demonstates the error?

Comment: Robert is right, without a sample for us to see how you handle the async requests it will be hard to answer. You will receive only guesses.

Comment: Sorry, thought you had a quick and dirty answer. I will refactor my code to be easier for you to analyze and post it asap.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone gets on this *really* old question, best guess is that the thread has been killed way before the download was completed, leading to file with size equal to 0.

For example let's compare what happens between

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"), "C:\\5MB.zip");
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"), "C:\\5MB.zip");
        }
    }
}
```

In the second case, as soon as the the download is started, the program exits leading to an interrupted download, which is manifested by the file being created on the C: drive with size 0.